# Probability multi-choice question

Tags: probability

I'm very confused on how to approach the following question; "Suppose there are $4$ horses in a race where ties are allowed. What is the probability that exactly $2$ pairs of horses will tie in this race?"

Options are: $\frac{2}{24}, \frac{2}{25}, \frac{4}{25}, \frac{4}{27}$

I tried to think that $2$ pairs of ties means $2$ came first and $2$ second, which is the equivalent of no. ways of putting $4$ objects into two slots with two in each which I got as $\binom{4}{2}$ then dividing that over the total ways of arranged $4$ objects into $4$ slots which I got as $4^4$. But that means the prob $=\frac{3}{128}$ which are none of the options, could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Exactly $2$ pairs or at least $2$ pairs? That would tell one if the cases with 3 horses tied and 4 horses tied have to be counted or not.

Comment: @AnkitSaha Exactly two pairs

Comment: The outcome can be something like three in the third place and one in the fourth, therefore at least one must be in the first place.

Comment: Either critical information has been omitted in your presentation of the problem, or the problem can not be solved.  There is no information given on the chance that a tie will occur.  For example suppose instead of 4 horses, there were only 2 horses.  How would you go about computing the probability that when the horses raced, the result would be a tie, rather than one of the two horses winning?

Comment: The question is very poorly written, and makes no sense as is. There is no way to determine the probability without being given exactly how the ordering is determined. In reality a tie would be extremely rare and depend on the accuracy of the clock. It would be completely unwarranted to assume that for example a 4-way tie is equally probable to a particular ordering without ties.

Comment: Note that it is not that unusual for the original problem to be so poorly worded as to defy solution.  Assuming no additional information is available, mathSE reviewers are (in effect) being asked to creatively speculate, via *reverse-engineering*, what the missing premises of the problem are.

Comment: @user2661923, How would I do it if I assume that the chances of two horses tying are equal to two horses not tying?

Comment: Assuming that a satisfying result is of the form $H_1, H_2$, tied, $H_3, H_4$ tied, and $H_1, H_4$ not tied, then there are $3$ different ways of pairing up the horses.  Assume that $(H_1,H_2)$ and $(H_3, H_4)$ are the two pairs.  Then chance of satisfactory results, are $$3 \times \left[\frac{1}{2}\right]^3 = \frac{3}{8}.$$  Here, the three coin-flip events are $H_1, H_2$ tied, $H_3, H_4$ tied, $H_1, H_4$ not tied.